# Dissecting a simple Javascript Closure

Tags: javascript, web, ecmascript-6, closures

When looking at the code for the addSuffix function

```
const addSuffix = (x) => {
    const concat = (y) => {
        return y + x
    }
return concat;
}

let add_ful = addSuffix("ful");
```

If I were to console.log(add_ful);  why do I get

```
(y) => {
    return y + x
}
```

instead of

```
(y) => {
    return y + "ful"
}
```

?

This is the most confusing point about closures for me, I understand that I can return a function, but I'm not sure where the reference to "ful" is being stored in the function.

Where is the value of x being stored in the add_ful function?

Comment: "Where is the value of x being stored in the add_ful function?" — In the variable `x`. You seem to be worrying too much about how the compiler/interpreter for JavaScript works instead of focusing on what the JS means.

Comment: The variable `x` doesn’t stop existing when `addSuffix` exits. That’s about it.

Comment: The thing you're trying to do is done with debuggers, not console.

Comment: You could also write it in a more concise way like `const addSuffix = x => y => y + x` where when invoked `addSuffix` returns you the `y => y + x` function by taking `x` under closure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value is not stored in the code. It does not get inlined at every place where `x` is used in the closure - the code still contains a variable `x` that is dynamically resolved when encountered (it's also still writable).

The value is stored in the scope object containing the variable, and this is referenced by the function object (that's what we call a [*closure*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming))). You can also inspect this hidden `[[Scope]]` slot in the devtools when you are logging the function object (and not just the function code produced by `.toString()`):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`console.log` logs a string representation of the function itself. It doesn't enquire into the state of the function and display the current values that are being referenced. It's just showing the syntax you used to create the function.

However, if you set a breakpoint and walk through the execution, you can see the state of the variables in scope using your debugging tools.